# OLED display on beaglebone running node.js

Tags: node.js, spi, beagleboneblack

Anyone know how I would get a BBB running on node.js to send text to an Adafruit ssd1306 display? The display uses SPI, not that I know what that is. There are write-ups on how to run this display on BBB using python, but I'm being told to do it in node.js since that is the language we are running our main program on.

update 6/4
Well adafruit says "The libraries are written in C++ for Arduino but could easily be ported to any microcontroller by rewriting the low-level pin access functions". Looks like that's my next path. I'm also trying to see if it is feasible to generate a complete bitmap in javascript, then pass it to the display without "porting". maybe the display has a bitmap file reader?

Comment: Check the write-ups in python and translate the code to node. It's pretty easy. Try to find node alternatives for all the python libraries they use.

Comment: perhaps you could find some information there [https://www.npmjs.org/package/spi](https://www.npmjs.org/package/spi)

Comment: Thanks! Trouble is the python library being used is actually an independently developed one so it's making it fun.